# How can I store 10x10 map / game field in MySQL workbench?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, database, mysql-workbench

I'm creating the game Sokoban in java.

The map / playing field is a 10x10 array.
One field in the array can contain one of the 5 different objects

1. Target Field
2. Chest
3. Player
4. Wall
5. Empty Field ( this is just a blank field where a player can walk over)

now i want to store that map in the MySql database i'm not so sure how to approach this.
I don't know what the table would look like. 
Later on i should be able to pull the map so a player can instantly play or modify the field.

I thought about using a string of 100 chars and each object has a specific char so i know the meaning and place of it.

Comment: IMHO you are better off serializing the structure you are using in java and just store that as a string/VARCHAR, just as you would save it to a file. There is no benefit to break that down into rows and colums just for the sake of utilizing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah so one approach would be to have a table that has a unique-key based on the column/row. Then you can store the key(s) relative to that column/row that link to the target field, the chest, the player, the wall, empty field.

Edit:
To answer your question on this answer, you can create a Location class that has and x and y that represents a spot in the grid. Then override equals/hashCode to make it unique. Then you can use a Map to store the Location and the relative GameObject at that location!

```java
    public class Location {

        private final int x;

        private final int y;

        private final int hashCode;

        public Location(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.hashCode = Objects.hash(x, y);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return hashCode;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            if (other == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (other instanceof Location) {
                Location otherLocation = (Location) other;

                return otherLocation.x == x && otherLocation.y == y;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    interface GameObject {

    }

    class TargetField implements GameObject {

    }

    class MyGame {

        private final Map<Location, GameObject> map;

        MyGame(Map<Location, GameObject> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        public void set(Location location, GameObject object) {
            map.put(location, object);
        }
    }
```

Comment: so that way i would basically create a matrix right?

Comment: Well, not necessarily. You could create an object like Position or Location that takes and x and y to represent the 2-d grid and then override equals/hashCode to use x and y. Then you could use a Map to maintain the relative object. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Well, yes, but in a way that you have multiple tables and rows. You wouldn't store the map as a String or JSON object. I mean, you could, but it's not conventional.

Comment: i'd just read it out and make a column key and  a column value

Comment: Yeah, but where you have different types of objects you might need to store the type as an enum for example, and an I'd for that object in that respective table.

Comment: I hope that helps man, if you need anything further hit me up in a conversation!